# Автопрокрутка страницы при клике на ссылку.

Tags: прокрутка, ссылки, javascript

Кликаю на ссылку, страница прокручивается вверх. Помогите пожалуйста отключить сие издевательство.

Answer (score 1):

Оно?

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false">бымс</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return function_which_returns_false()">дымс</a>
```

Comment: Возможно. Но как использовать это, если onclick уже занят? У меня к onclick привязана функция. Не могу понять.

Comment: Внимательно смотрим на вторую строчку. Потом на первую. Потом снова на вторую. Вбиваем в гуглопереводчике `function which returns false`. Потом смотрим на свою функцию, думаем...

Comment: Хоть и не до конца понял как, но получилось. Спасибо тебе Картмэн, что уберег мою психику от срыва.